# Вывести значение переменной python на странице html

Tags: python, html

Не понимаю, что я делаю не так.
Из POST-запроса передается значение в переменную `getnumb`, которую хочу напечатать на странице.
Просто ничего не происходит.

Код Python:

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        getnumb = request.form['getnumb']
        return redirect('index.html')
    else:
        return render_template("base.html")
```

Код index.html:

```
<form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="getnumb"><br>
        <button type="submit">ADD</button>
</form>
<h3>{{getnumb}}</h3>
```

Comment: Я имею исключительно шапошное знакомство с html но Вы уверены что должно быть `frOm` а не `fOrm`?

Comment: Действительно, ошибка была еще и в <form>.
В любом случае, переменная `getnumb` не выводится.

Comment: Опять таки, не очень знаком с Джанго или Фласк, но в упор не вижу в каком месте Вы передаете переменную `getnumb` для того, чтобы она была использована именно при создании index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return render_template("base.html", value=getnumb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Моя ошибка была в том, что я скопировал сюда немного неверный код. Фактически все работало, как часы.
Код из index.html был скопирован из блока , в котором задавался цвет бэкграунда. И когда загружалась страница с переменной getnumb - цвет текста сливался с фоном "задника", по этому текст было не видно. Узнал я это, когда открыл код страницы.